# Probability of Graph getting disconnected

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I am researching on **decentralized storage network**, where each **node** in the network will be connected to $d$ other nodes.
 When any node shares a file, it is propagated to all other nodes (I'm assuming we have a connected network). So, the shared data will reach all the nodes.
 But suppose now that there are some **malicious nodes** who doesn't propagate the data to its neighbors. The **malicious nodes** are like deleted nodes as they do not maintaining the connection. With malicious nodes there is chance that the network gets disconnected (**data doesn't reach to all the nodes**).
 I need to figure out what would be the probability that the network will get disconnected if **$k$ ($k < n$) nodes** are malicious.

The mathematical problem I need to solve is suppose, there is a **$d$-regular** **graph** with $n$ nodes. Now we randomly **delete $k$ nodes** out of them. What is the **probability** of the graph getting **disconnected**?

I'm not able to figure out where to start. If there is any literature to read in this topic please share?

Comment: Did you try with $k$ being $1$, $2$, $3$, ...? What are your finding?